# Suppress all alerts for a specific Monit service check?

Tags: linux, monit

Under my [Monit 5.4](http://mmonit.com/monit/) installation, I'm interested in suppressing all alerts for a particular service check.

Given the following stanza:

```
check process nslcd
        with pidfile "/var/run/nslcd/nslcd.pid" every 2 cycles
        start program = "/sbin/service nslcd start"
        stop program = "/sbin/service nslcd stop"
        if 10 restarts within 11 cycles then timeout
        if cpu usage > 95% for 11 cycles then restart
        if totalmemory > 64 MB then restart
```

What is the cleanest approach to suppressing all alerts for *all* actions on this service check? I'm familiar with the `noalert` function, but it does not seem to work well for my use case. Other Monit alerts for other services/daemons are fine to continue.

Comment: Did the set non-real e-mail may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to add an email address to the alert field for each check. Using a fake address sufficed.